# Spark Dataframe manipulation

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Input Dataframe:

| caseid | indicator |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | STP |
| 1 | non-STP |
| 2 | STP |
| 3 | STP |
| 3 | non-STP |

output Dataframe:

| caseid | indicator |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | non-STP |
| 2 | STP |
| 3 | non-STP |

Hello all, I would be really grateful if someone can help me in the above dataframe. in the output dataframe, I only want to keep the cases where the indicator is non-STP, whereas in the cases where the cases in STP keep that as it is.
Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1):

You could try with `groupby` and then check if values contain `non-STP`.

Example:

```py
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
import pyspark.sql.functions as F


spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
data = [
    {"caseid": "1", "indicator": "STP"},
    {"caseid": "1", "indicator": "non-STP"},
    {"caseid": "2", "indicator": "STP"},
    {"caseid": "3", "indicator": "STP"},
    {"caseid": "3", "indicator": "non-STP"},
]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data)
df = (
    df.groupBy("caseid")
    .agg(F.concat_ws(",", F.collect_list(F.col("indicator"))).alias("indicator"))
    .orderBy("caseid")
)
df = df.withColumn(
    "indicator",
    F.when(F.col("indicator").contains("non-STP"), F.lit("non-STP")).otherwise(
        F.lit("STP")
    ),
)
```

Result:

```
root
 |-- caseid: string (nullable = true)
 |-- indicator: string (nullable = false)

+------+---------+                                                              
|caseid|indicator|
+------+---------+
|1     |non-STP  |
|2     |STP      |
|3     |non-STP  |
+------+---------+
```